# Is there a tool to monitor the latest version of db4o?

Tags: db4o

I have tried the Object Manager and the Boo browser, but none of these work with the latest DB4O file format.

Comment: You mean you want to be notified when they release a new version?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the old versions don't work with the latest db4o. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Object Manager which comes with db4o itself should be able to view the database-files. Otherwise it's a but a you should report it.

The Object Manager which comes with db4o is a Eclipse-plugin for the Java db4o version and a Visual Studio Plugin for the .NET version.

In the Java-Version it is in the ome directory of the db4o distribution. You can unzip the Object Manager. Then add that directory as a Eclipse update-site and install the Object Manager.

For the .NET Version there's a omnomn2005, omn2008 and omn2010 folder. Pick the version acording to the Visual Studio version and install it.